# How to get data from json using python

Tags: python, arrays, json

json:

```
{"id":"1","name":"Smokey Mountain Ski Club","terrain_park":"Unknown","night_skiing":"Unknown","operating_status":"Unknown","latitude":52.977947,"longitude":-66.92094,"user":{"id":"7","username":"skier"},"tags":[{"id":"1","name":"Downhill"}],"ski_maps":[{"id":"902"}],"open_ski_maps":[],"created":"2008-04-13T00:11:59+00:00","regions":[{"id":"335","name":"Newfoundland and Labrador"}]}
```

I've done so that this data stores in a "data" variable..

I am trying to output all the data like: "key" : "value" list

```
for q in data:
print q + ': ' data[q]
```

This code outputs:

```
night_skiing: Unknown
name: Smokey Mountain Ski Club

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I understand what's this error about but I don't know how to solve it..

So my question is how to put all the data from this array into variables?

Comment: Are you purposely trying to avoid importing the json module, and using json.loads?

Comment: this isnt a `json` question, its an output formatting question

Comment: You don't give any indication how you load the json data, the code sample you posted has two syntax errors in two lines (indentation and a missing `+`), your error has nothing to do with JSON, and you obviously didn't thoroughly search for the error message you get. Please spend some more effort researching and presenting your question next time...

Comment: Yea, there are some mistakes..  i was mostly focusing on this output, but Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When e.g. `q == tags`, your `print` line becomes:

```
print "tags" + ': ' + [{"id":"1","name":"Downhill"}]
```

Python is strongly typed, so you can't implicitly concatenate a (unicode) string with a list. You need to be explicit about what you want to happen, i.e. that the list (`data[q]`) should be converted to a string:

```
print q + ': ' str(data[q])
```

or, much better, use `str.format` rather than string concatenation (or the old-fashioned `%` formatting):

```
print "{0}: {1}".format(q, data[q])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a small example:

```
import json

try:
  # parse JSON string from socket
  p = json.loads(msg)
except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
  logging.debug("JSON format error: " + msg.strip() )
else:
  # remote control is about controlling the model (thrust and attitude)
  com = "%d,%d,%d,%d" % (p['r'], p['p'], p['t'], p['y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that not all your data values are strings, and you are treating them as strings.
Using a str format will convert the values to strings.  Try this:

```
for q in data.iteritems():
    print '%s: %s' % q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = '{"id":"1","name":"Smokey Mountain Ski Club","terrain_park":"Unknown","night_skiing":"Unknown","operating_status":"Unknown","latitude":52.977947,"longitude":-66.92094,"user":{"id":"7","username":"skier"},"tags":[{"id":"1","name":"Downhill"}],"ski_maps":[{"id":"902"}],"open_ski_maps":[],"created":"2008-04-13T00:11:59+00:00","regions":[{"id":"335","name":"Newfoundland and Labrador"}]}'

dataDict = json.loads(data)

for key in dataDict.keys():
    print key + ': ' + str(dataDict[key])
```

Comment: that also worked! thanks.. but one more thing: when in returns (tags: [{u'id': u'1', u'name': u'Downhill'}] ), how do i get the "name" field from this line? I've tried to get it in many ways but i couldn't :(

Comment: dataDict['tags'] points to an array. I suspect dataDict['tags'][0]['name'] will work.